# Symfony: Is there any way to render a twig template using a relative path to the template?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In the [Template Naming and Locations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#template-naming-locations) section in the Symfony docs it says:

> Symfony2 uses a bundle:controller:template string syntax for
>   templates. This allows for several different types of templates, each
>   which lives in a specific location:
>
> - AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:index.html.twig: This syntax is used to specify a template for a specific page. The three parts of the string, each
>     separated by a colon (:), mean the following:
> - AcmeBlogBundle: (bundle) the template lives inside the AcmeBlogBundle (e.g. src/Acme/BlogBundle); Blog: (controller)
>     indicates that the template lives inside the Blog subdirectory of
>     Resources/views;
> - index.html.twig: (template) the actual name of the file is index.html.twig.

I want to parse a twig template and persist the html into the property of a doctrine entity during my data fixtures bootstrapping process like so:

```
// let's say it finds ./Data/Product/camera_description.html.twig
$productDescriptionTemplate = __DIR__.sprintf(
    '/Data/Product/%s_description.html.twig', 
    $product->getName()
);

$product->setDescription(
    $this->container->get('templating')->render(
        $productDescriptionTemplate, 
        array()
    )
);

$em->flush();
```

Which throws the following exception:

```
# would actually be an absolute path
[InvalidArgumentException]
  Template name "./Data/Product/camera_description.html.twig 
  " is not valid (format is "bundle:section:template.format.engine").
```

Yes I could move the product description templates to `path/to/bundle/Resources/views/` but I am more interested in whether it is possible to circumvent this convention: Is there a way  to give the twig templating engine the *relative or absolute* path to a twig template and have it render it *not having* to use the convention `bundle:controller:template`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064914/how-to-load-a-template-from-full-path-in-the-template-engine-twig

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also create a new namespace as described here :  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/namespaced_paths.html

for example :

```
paths:
        "%kernel.root_dir%/../Data/Product/": product
```

which should allow you to write :

```
'product::%s_description.html.twig',
```

or

```
'@product/%s_description.html.twig'
```

Comment: After reviewing the [Twig Documentation for Developers: Built in Loaders](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#built-in-loaders) I believe your answer is the best solution as there is **no built in way** to simply pass Twig a relative path to a template. It may be possible if I [created my own loader](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#create-your-own-loader) but that is simply too involved for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want use `bundle:controller:template` syntax, then you could try using **[twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html)** directly:

```
$product->setDescription(
    $this->container->get('twig')->render(
        $productDescriptionTemplate, 
        array()
    )
);
```

Comment: I tried this and received the same exception mentioned in the original post.