# Symfony: using twig service to render a template using absolute path

Tags: php, symfony, twig, template-engine, absolute-path

Assuming that I have a Symfony service where I'm injecting the `@twig` service:

```
my_service:
    class: Path\To\My\Service
    arguments: ['@twig']
```

so I have the `@twig` stored in `$this->twig` in my service class:

```
public function __construct($twig)
{
    $this->twig = $twig;
}
```

when I try to render a template using an absolute path:

`$result = $this->twig->render('/path/to/my/template.html.twig', $params);`

the problem is that twig interprets the absolute path as the name of the file and it will only look inside the pre-configured directories:

> Unable to find template "/path/to/my/template.html.twig" (looked into:
>   /.../app/Resources/views,
>   /.../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form).

is there a way to tell to twig to handle it as an absolute path?

Comment: Try to look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064914/how-to-load-a-template-from-full-path-in-the-template-engine-twig

Comment: Just to be clear, you want your twig file to be defined from the root of your server? like `/var/www/projectName/app/Resources/Dir/File.html.twig`

Comment: @Mattia that's not what I need: that question is about using twig by creating a new instance (`new Twig_Environment`), but in my case I'm using the instance which already exists as a service inside the Symfony service container (`@twig`)

Comment: @goto yes the templates I need to reference are inside the symfony project

Comment: @ShinDarth You need to read the other answer of the question that Mattia listed

Comment: @DarkBee which one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20265872/446594

Comment: @DarkBee, again that question (ant its answers) is about creating a NEW instance of the Twig Environment. My case is different: I'd like to use the existing one which lives inside the Symfony service container  (the service `@twig`). So I do not want to re-create the environment or its loader.

Comment: @ShinDarth It's not about creating a new instance. It's about extending and altering existing code to add more functions to the class. Loading templates from an absolutes path is not a standard thing inside `twig`, so you need to modify existing code to do the magic. Where do you see them creating a new instance then?

Comment: then can you please explain, once I extend the class, how it will impact on the already existing twig env instance as a symfony service (`@twig`) ? that's the missing point for me. If you could answer this question, posting an example of how to accomplish what I'm asking, I would be grateful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You just need to register the custom file loader in your configuration and thats that actualy. Because the custom class extends the default one all the other templates won't be affected but you will be able to load absolute paths